# How to select an id in route pass it into the controller and fetch data against that id and redirect it view again in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

How to pass id from veiw into controller in then into another view again??

Comment: Your statement is unclear. Please do elaborate if you can.

Comment: I wants to pass id from a view to controller and then select records against that id from db using query builder and then wants to pass that records to another view.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this a basic question you should be able to search it anywhere on the internet. any how below is the solution.

web/routes.php:

```
Route::get('user/{id}','USerController@find')->name('user.get');
```

Or by passing user object in the route:

```
Route::get('user/{user}','USerController@find')->name('user.get');
```

UserController:

the below function accepts user object as a parameter in the route we defined above.

```
public function find(user $user)
{
    return view('user.detail',compact('user'))
}
```

or

```
public function find($id)
{
    $user = USer::find($id);
    return view('user.detail',compact('user'))
}
```

resources/view/user/detail.blade.php:

```
     {{ $user -> name }}
     {{ $user -> email }}
```

and in order visit the route **user.find** use the below line:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.get', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary"> View Detail </a>
```

No you can use this code as reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, maybe i will help you:

```
public function show(int $id): View
{
    $video = Video::find($id);

    return view('video.show', ['video' => $video]);
}
```

Comment: I wants to pass id from a view to controller and then select records against that id from db using query builder and then wants to pass that records to another view.

Answer (score 0):

first solution is .
change route

```
Route::get('/show_vedio/{$id}', 'VedioController@show')->name(show_videos);
```

and use this `{{ route('show_vedios', $vedio->id )}}` in href